# Measuring objects real size from image python

Tags: python, image-processing, diplib

I need to measure the size of plants from images. I made lots of research but none of them answer my question.

I know the distance between the plants and camera and using this information I want to calculate the objects real size in my case plants size.

On the internet I found that using some reference objects they can measure, however I can not use the reference objects.

I found similar questions on the stackoverflow, and I tried to proposed solutions and none of them work for me.

```
import pydip as dip
import math

# Load image and set pixel size
img = dip.ImageReadTIFF('pic3.jpg')
```

I try to use pyDIP but, I got some errors. So it did not work.

Comment: you are member since today so i am just advicing you to try some code, then give your codes in your question otherwise you will get many downvotes on your question.

Comment: you are asking so broad topic.

Comment: Measuring items without a reference object is impossible in my mind. You can  take a photo of space or a photo of a bacteria. Without any reference, the bacteria will appear bigger than the stars in the galaxy. Ofcourse this is not the case in real life.

Comment: But in that case I know the distance between camera and the objects. I made some research and there some way to calculate size of objects without reference images.

Comment: This is a Hard Problem, one that hasn't been properly solved by *anyone*, because it requires a lot of image recognition - one of the things that computers are notoriously bad at. [This article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/) and [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/04/measuring-distance-between-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) are the most relevant, and possibly most helpful, things I could find for your particular situation, so good luck.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thanks for your advice but  I found these articles and I tried them. Measuring distance between objects in an image with OpenCV is works well. However ı have to do that without using the reference image.

Comment: @JainilPatel thanks for your advice. I will add the entire code. However I could not find the where I found that code, as I cannot put reference to that code, I did not put entire code. But I will put entire code. Thank You

Comment: @JainilPatel Right know, there is one plant.

Comment: I did not understand the way you say. I sounds easy, but it is hard to build math behinds it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035721/how-to-measure-object-size-in-real-world-in-terms-of-measurement-like-inches-cen

Comment: the math behind it....

Comment: I saw it, but most of the links are broken in the accepted answer.